# SP2013: Calendar view multiday not respecting time

Tags: calendar, view, sharepoint-calendar

I havn't been using Sharepoint calendars much, so this might not be a new thing, but here goes.

I cannot for the life of me get my calendar to respect the time part of an event whenever it covers more than one day.

Say I have an event on the 1/4-2015 from 10.00-12.00 everything is perfecty fine. Now if I expand the event to the 2/4-2015 12.00 (Thus covering two days) the event is represented in the view as an all day event covering the full two days.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Other than making multiple events (Which isn't really a solution)?

BR
Morten

Comment: This is default behavior of multiday view in SharePoint calendar (and in many third party calendars also). I guess it can not be changed in SharePoint.

Comment: Whoa that's really dumb - especially since it also reflects on the free/busy lookup (The entire day is marked as busy even if the meeting from the day before ends at 9 AM) :-(